# Adding a header for each group of data instead of a common header

Tags: excel, vba

The below code thanks to @FaneDuru helped me copying filtered data to a new sheet, what I need to tweak is **copying each set of data with a separate header instead of one main header for all data** and a**lso cut data instead of copy**

Code:

```
Sub CopyFilteredCustomersByCompanyNames()
     Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, wsComp As Worksheet, dictC As Object
     Dim rngFilt As Range, arrCust() As Variant, arrFilt, i As Long
     
     arrCust = Array("108169651", "108169651", "108169430", "108169430", "108168704", "108169596") 'place here the 10 specific customers name
     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'use here the workbook you need
     Set ws = ActiveSheet    'use here the necessary sheet (the one to be processed)
     
     If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
     
     Set rngFilt = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion: ' Debug.Print rngFilt.Address: Stop
     arrFilt = rngFilt.Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
     
     'extract the uneque Company Names:
     Set dictC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     For i = 2 To UBound(arrFilt)
        If arrFilt(i, 1) <> "" Then
                dictC(arrFilt(i, 1)) = dictC(arrFilt(i, 1)) + 1
        End If
     Next i
     
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'optimization to make code faster
     Dim keyC As Variant, rngF As Range
     For Each keyC In dictC.Keys   'iterate between dictionary keys (A:A company names)
            rngFilt.AutoFilter 1, keyC                    'first filter by dict key
            rngFilt.AutoFilter 4, arrCust, xlFilterValues 'second by array of customers numbers
            
            Set wsComp = Nothing
            'insert the necessary sheets, name them (if not existing), clear if existing and copy the filtered range
            Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
              On Error Resume Next
                  Set wsComp = wb.Worksheets(keyC)
              On Error GoTo 0
              If Not wsComp Is Nothing Then
                    wsComp.Cells.ClearContents
                Else
                    Set wsComp = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)
                    wsComp.Name = keyC
              End If
              rngFilt.Rows(1).Copy ' copy the headers columns width
              wsComp.Range("A1").Resize(, rngFilt.Rows(1).Columns.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            
             On Error Resume Next
                Set rngF = rngFilt.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             On Error GoTo 0
             If Not rngF Is Nothing Then
                 rngF.Copy wsComp.Range("A1")
             End If
             ws.ShowAllData
          Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
         Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     Next keyC
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
     MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

What I want data to look like (separate data by header)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Link to Faneduru profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233308/faneduru

If I can't cut and paste data, I used the below code to filter for the copied data to new sheets and delete it by using the "Or formula" and filtered for True and deleted those rows as the filter only takes 2 criteria.

```
    Sub Delete()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

   lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Rows.End(xlDown).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:AD" & lastRow)

ActiveSheet.Range("AD1").Value = "TRUE/FALSE"
ActiveSheet.Range("AD2").Formula = "=OR(D2=""108169651"",D2=""108169430"",D2=""108168704"",D2=""108169596"")"
ActiveSheet.Range("AD2:AD" & lastRow).Formula = ActiveSheet.Range("AD2").Formula
   With rng
.AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:="True"

        

.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

I added the call sub for the above code at the end of your (**CopyFilteredCustomersByCompanyNames**) Sub:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFilteredCustomersByCompanyNames()
     Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, wsComp As Worksheet, dictC As Object
     Dim rngFilt As Range, arrCust() As Variant, arrFilt, i As Long
     
     'Array of Distributors which we need to add in new sheets
     arrCust = Array("108169651", "108169651", "108169430", "108169430", "108168704", "108169596") 'place here the 10 specific customers name
     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'use here the workbook you need
     Set ws = ActiveSheet    'use here the necessary sheet (the one to be processed)
     
     'Clear all Filters if any
     If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
     
     Set rngFilt = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion: ' Debug.Print rngFilt.Address: Stop
     arrFilt = rngFilt.Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
     
     'extract the unique Company Names:
     Set dictC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     For i = 2 To UBound(arrFilt)
        If arrFilt(i, 1) <> "" Then
                dictC(arrFilt(i, 1)) = dictC(arrFilt(i, 1)) + 1
        End If
     Next i
     
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'optimization to make code faster
     Dim keyC As Variant, rngF As Range, rngF1 As Range
     For Each keyC In dictC.Keys   'iterate between dictionary keys (A:A company names)
            rngFilt.AutoFilter 1, keyC                    'first filter by dict key
            rngFilt.AutoFilter 4, arrCust, xlFilterValues 'second by array of customers numbers
            
            Set wsComp = Nothing
            'insert the necessary sheets, name them (if not existing), clear if existing and copy the filtered range
            Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
              On Error Resume Next
                  Set wsComp = wb.Worksheets(keyC)
              On Error GoTo 0
              If Not wsComp Is Nothing Then
                    wsComp.Cells.ClearContents
                Else
                    Set wsComp = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)
                    wsComp.Name = keyC
              End If
              rngFilt.Rows(1).Copy ' copy the headers columns width
              wsComp.Range("A1").Resize(, rngFilt.Rows(1).Columns.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            
             On Error Resume Next
                Set rngF1 = Nothing
                Set rngF1 = rngFilt.Resize(rngFilt.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible):
                Set rngF = rngFilt.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             On Error GoTo 0
             If Not rngF1 Is Nothing Then
                 rngF.Copy wsComp.Range("A1")
                 InsertHeaders wsComp
             Else
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                   wb.Worksheets(keyC).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
             End If
             'ws.ShowAllData
          Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
         Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     Next keyC
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  ws.AutoFilterMode = False
 

     'MsgBox "Ready..."
           
      Delete
End Sub
```

IS that correct or do you have any other recommendations

Comment: Have you tried do modify this code? Where do you run into troubles?

Comment: @Shrotter I Tried to cut data instead of copy but can't and add header for each group of copied rows but can't specify exactly how to do it, still searching

Comment: I have in mind a solution. It involves another function/Sub to be called by the existing code, able to check if more then a unique code exists, if so, sort, apply subtotals, detect the subtotal cells and place them in a Union Range, then copy the header on the Union range rows. Finally, remove subtotals, which only should be used temporarily, to rapidly detect the rows where the headers to be inserted. But I am on the road now and I will be able to put it in practice after some hours, when I will be at home.

Comment: @FaneDuru i will search for the steps you mentioned above and try it rn. Thanks!

Comment: This is good. I learn better when you discover by yourself the way of doing... But I am at home now. I estimate that in less than 5 minutes I will post an answer.

Comment: Totally agree, I already add your comments to my manual for studying.

Comment: @FaneDuru I added the code in the body of the post to delete filtered data instead of cut and paste, Kindly check and tell me your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next solution to a standard module (instead of the existing code):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFilteredCustomersByCompanyNames()
     Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, wsComp As Worksheet, dictC As Object
     Dim rngFilt As Range, arrCust() As Variant, arrFilt, i As Long
     
     arrCust = Array("108169651", "108169651", "108169430", "108169430", "108168704", "108169596") 'place here the 10 specific customers name
     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'use here the workbook you need
     Set ws = ActiveSheet    'use here the necessary sheet (the one to be processed)
     
     If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
     
     Set rngFilt = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion: ' Debug.Print rngFilt.Address: Stop
     arrFilt = rngFilt.Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
     
     'extract the uneque Company Names:
     Set dictC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     For i = 2 To UBound(arrFilt)
        If arrFilt(i, 1) <> "" Then
                dictC(arrFilt(i, 1)) = dictC(arrFilt(i, 1)) + 1
        End If
     Next i
     
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'optimization to make code faster
     Dim keyC As Variant, rngF As Range, rngF1 As Range
     For Each keyC In dictC.Keys   'iterate between dictionary keys (A:A company names)
            rngFilt.AutoFilter 1, keyC                    'first filter by dict key
            rngFilt.AutoFilter 4, arrCust, xlFilterValues 'second by array of customers numbers
            
            Set wsComp = Nothing
            'insert the necessary sheets, name them (if not existing), clear if existing and copy the filtered range
            Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
              On Error Resume Next
                  Set wsComp = wb.Worksheets(keyC)
              On Error GoTo 0
              If Not wsComp Is Nothing Then
                    wsComp.Cells.ClearContents
                Else
                    Set wsComp = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)
                    wsComp.Name = keyC
              End If
              rngFilt.Rows(1).Copy ' copy the headers columns width
              wsComp.Range("A1").Resize(, rngFilt.Rows(1).Columns.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            
             On Error Resume Next
                Set rngF1 = Nothing
                Set rngF1 = rngFilt.Resize(rngFilt.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible):
                Set rngF = rngFilt.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             On Error GoTo 0
             If Not rngF1 Is Nothing Then
                 rngF.Copy wsComp.Range("A1")
                 InsertHeaders wsComp
             Else
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                   wb.Worksheets(keyC).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
             End If
             ws.ShowAllData
          Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
         Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     Next keyC
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
     MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Sub InsertHeaders(ws As Worksheet)
     Dim rngSub As Range, lastR As Long, firstAddress As String, rngUnion As Range
     Dim i As Long, dict As Object
     
     'check if more than one unique Account exists:
     lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     For i = 2 To lastR
            dict(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value) = vbNullString
     Next i

     If dict.Count < 2 Then Exit Sub 'for only one customer code, no need of other headers...
     
     'sort the range:
     ws.UsedRange.Sort key1:=ws.UsedRange.Cells(1, 4), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
     
     'place Subtotals based on Account (customer number):
     ws.UsedRange.Subtotal GroupBy:=4, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(12), _
                         Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
       
     'delete last two rows:
     lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
     ws.Rows(lastR - 1 & ":" & lastR).Delete: 'Stop
     
     'place all cells containing "SUBTOTAL'" in formula in a Union Range:
      Set rngSub = ws.UsedRange.Columns(12).Find(What:="SUBTOTAL", After:=ws.UsedRange.Columns(12).Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart)
       If rngSub Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       firstAddress = rngSub.Address
       addToRange rngUnion, rngSub
       Do
            Set rngSub = ws.UsedRange.FindNext(rngSub)
            addToRange rngUnion, rngSub
       Loop While rngSub.Address <> firstAddress
       
       'copy the header row to the places of Subtotals rows:
        With ws.Rows("1:1")
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Copy rngUnion.EntireRow 'copy the header in all Union range
       End With
      'remove Subtotals (needed only temporary):
      ws.UsedRange.RemoveSubtotal
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range) 'sub adding the new range to a Union one...
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Your existing code has only one modification: The new sub call:

```
  rngF.Copy wsComp.Range("A1")
  InsertHeaders wsComp
```

instead of

```
 rngF.Copy wsComp.Range("A1")
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Please, download your updated workbook (using above solution) from [here](https://easyupload.io/iz4h2k). Now I need to leave home, but I would have my mobile phone. If something not clear or goes wrong, I can see your message but I can solve the problem, if any, when I will be at home again...

Comment: Brilliant! Worked flawlessly as usual.

Comment: And if i want to cut data instead of copy, should i use >>  rngF.Cut wsComp.Range("A1")

Comment: @Martin What do you mean by cutting? Why would you like to cut anything from processed sheet and paste to the Company one? Like method, it is correct ( `Cut` followed by `Destination`). If not followed by destination, the `Cut` range stays in clipboard memory and can be pasted in a second step. I cannot understand it as business wise/logic... I think all the range should be available for the next company code cases.

Comment: I cut because the specific customers extracted have a special case and need to be removed from the main data file to new sheets before processing further., so instead of copying data to new sheet, i wan to cut these data to new sheets

Comment: @Martin I'm afraid that `Cut` does not work in the same way with `Copy` for **discontinuous/filtered ranges**. So, you should firstly copy and then delete the copied rows. But you should copy headers included and delete only the other filtered rows...

Comment: @Martin If you will do it by yourself, good for you! This is the way to learn. If not, try posting a new question and tag me. In this case you didn't do it, even if I offered myself to help... I found your question by chance.

Comment: @Martin Take care when make tests! Try the new code on a backup workbook. If you succeed to cut the rows, **if you try the code once more, it will delete all resulted sheets**!

Comment: I tried to tag you but Stackoverflow wouldn't allow tags in questions. :/

Comment: @Martin I said (in the previous question) "to tag me here", meaning in comments of the question where we changed a lot of messages. And about the above idea, in order to avoid loosing the processed companies sheets it is good to place a marker at the end of the code, which to be checked when it starts...